# Routes & Middleware - Location change from version 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm currently upgrading a Laravel application from 5.2 to a current version (7.x). Actually I'm doing the the upgrade from Laravel 5.4 to 5.5. Now I recognized, that in 5.3 the location of `routes.php` (former `app\Http`) changed to `routes\web.php` and `routes\api.php`.
I'm having trouble, to transfer the different routes into the specific files.

I've copied the files of the `routes` folder into the project and changed the `RouteServiceProvider` accordingly to the github code from 5.5 (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.5/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

My former `routes.php` looked like this:

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
// all web routes without authorization go here:
...

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // all routes which need authorization go here:
    ...

    });
});
```

Now I've put all routes without authorization into `web.php` and all routes which need authorization into the `api.php` file.

But this configuration does not work. It does not show the pages.
The crazy thing is, that also no error logs are produced, so `laravel.log` is empty.

What is wrong in the `RouteServiceProvider` or what do I have to change that my routes are working again.

Comment: Your `RouteServiceProvider.php` looks fine to me. Are you utilising the api middleware group? Typically you would put your authed routes in your `web.php` unless you're using the api middleware/building an API. Apologies for any confusion on my part. What does a sample of your `php artisan route list` look like?

Comment: Looking at your old routes file you should not put your routes that need authorization into the `api.php` file since they are dependent on the `web` middleware group, which is automatically executed for all routes inside `web.php`, but not for routes inside `api.php` since routes inside `api.php` should be stateless.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I put the auth routes into the web.php file it works. I need to check again for what api exactly is for.